# access attached volume in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

My pod is making heap dump on `-XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/my-shared`. I need to get heap dumps from that directory, but I can not ssh to the pod because of permissions. I have found that this path refers to a mounted volume. My idea is to ssh to that volume but I don't know how

In `kubectl pod describe` I get the following info:

```
Init Containers:
    Mounts:
      /var/my-shared from shared (rw)

Volumes:
  shared:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/my-shared/my-project
    HostPathType:
```

Sorry if the description is vague - I'm pretty new to Kubernetes

Comment: you cant ssh into a volume. go to the path on the host (the hostPath), and get the data from there.

Comment: @suren what is a host path? I can not ssh to my container if you mean this by the host path

Comment: your container has a path that is mapped to the hostPath on your host (the node on which the container is running). no need to access the container, if you can't.

Comment: Are u saying that I need to ssh to the node that has my pod running? Is the only way to do using ssh with private key? can I do it using k8s?

Comment: you can access the pod using kubernetes, or the node by ssh.